# How to show :$\inf\sum_{i=1}^m z_i\log(z_i)=-\log(m)$

Tags: analysis

$$\inf\left(\sum_{i=1}^m z_i\log(z_i)\right)=-\log(m)$$
where $z_1+z_2+...z_m=1$

I have been trying to figure out this equality but I couldn't.
could you please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Jensen's inequality, applying to $f(x)=x\log(x)$ for $x>0$, we have

$$\left(\dfrac{\sum x_i}{m}\right)\log
\left(\dfrac{\sum x_i}{m}\right)\le \dfrac{\sum x_i\log(x_i)}{m}$$.

Thus, $\frac{1}{m}\log(\frac{1}{m})\le \dfrac{\sum x_i\log(x_i)}{m}$.i.e. $-\log(m)\le {\sum x_i\log(x_i)}$.

So, $-\log m$ is a lower bound for all the sums defined by the LHS. To prove that indeed is the infimum, we can take $x_i=\frac{1}{m}$ for all $i\in\{1,...,m\}$ and the result holds.